# Unable to update core: Snap has no update available

Tags: updates, 20.04, software-center, snap

[image: see this]

Why is this coming? I don't know what to do.

Comment: have you tried `sudo snap refresh` in the terminal?

Comment: Could be an issue with the server. In that case, just have a bit patience.

Comment: I had the same problem - this (i.e. "sudo snap refresh" ) fixed the problem (after re-booting). Thanks for your help totalynotanoob.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu store snap update fails](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1321217/ubuntu-store-snap-update-fails)

Answer (score 3):

This problem shows up sometimes if multiple updates are listed and updated in one go.

The suggestions given in the answers to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1321217/ubuntu-store-snap-update-fails) generally solve the problem.

```
sudo killall snap-store
sudo snap refresh
```

`killall snap-store` forces reloading of the software catalog and that seems to fix the mixed up metadata.