# Ubuntu store snap update fails

Tags: updates, snap, ubuntu-store

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. When I go into the Ubuntu Store, I find that there are two updates ready for `snapd` and core. When I try to apply the updates, I get this error:

> Unable to update snapd: snap has no updates available

I get the same error if I try to update core with snapd above replaced by core.

What I've done to solve the problem: I tried running `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`, which I didn't believe would solve the problem, but it was worth a try. It didn't work, as expected. I then typed up the error on the internet to see if that would help. I found nothing except [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1275552/unable-to-update-core-snap-has-no-update-available) question on AskUbuntu by user preIdiot that is similar to mine but has no answers. I tried running the `sudo snap refresh` command suggested in one of the comments, and got `All snaps up to date`.

Honestly, I'm really confused at this point. The Ubuntu Store says there are updates, but snap says there are none. What is going on, and how can I fix it, if applicable?

I'm not sure if this will help, as the issue is software rather than hardware related, but posting my specs can't hurt, as provided by `neofetch`:

[image: system specs]

**UPDATE**: I'm not sure where I'm supposed to be making updates, but I'll do it here for now. The problem has disappeared on its own.

Comment: I don't think the question should've been closed. Anyway, my guess is that the problem could be in incomplete system upgrade, needing to reboot... I managed to make my problem disappear.

Comment: There's no point in handing a question on a problem that disappeared in its own or goes away with a reboot. There's nothing anybody can do about the former and the latter is step 0 of IT troubleshooting.

Answer (score 42):

Ubuntu users who use 20.04.4 LTS or later can use:

```
killall snap-store
```

Comment: So, what's going on here, why should the `snap-store` be killed?

Comment: Looks like it forces re-downloading the software catalog..

Answer (score 14):

Just type

```
snap refresh
```

and reopen Ubuntu Software

Comment: This did it for me, but I had to type `sudo snap refresh` to get the script properly running.

Answer (score 5):

Open a terminal and type

```
killall gnome-software
```

You shouldn't need to use `sudo`.

On reopening `Software` it will re-index and should remove the problem.

[reference to a similar issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1321097/snapd-runtime-environment-update)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if I'm right on this, but isn't the app store in Ubuntu 20.04 called the `snap-store`? So shouldn't `gnome-software` be replaced by `snap-store`? Or should I just use the suggested command verbatim?

Comment: It's what worked for me with the same issue. In the linked questions/answers you will see that there is confusion around gnome-software and snap-store.